# Regex in Apache Derby

Tags: regex, stored-procedures, derby

Is it possible to extract a string from a varchar field in Apache Derby?

I'd like to use a regular expression. Something like:

```
select
    regex('Joe Bloggs', '(\w+)\s(\w+)', 2) as surname
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: You might be able to extract the parts with `'Joe Bloggs'.replaceAll("(\w+)\s\w+", "$1")` (to get `Joe`) and `'Joe Bloggs'.replaceAll("\w+\s(\w+)", "$2")` to get `Bloggs`.

Comment: That looks interesting Wiktor, how can I use that in an sql statement?

Comment: No idea, I just had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075355/search-java-string-for-special-characters-before-inserting-into-derbydb-varcha, and suggested a similar approach here :)

Answer (score 4):

Apache Derby doesn't have a native function, but it's possible to create your own and call it from the database.

First, create the java method that will process the regular expression:

```
package DbExamples.StoredProcedures;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringUtilities {

    public static String regex(String source, String regex, int index) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

        String result = null;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.groupCount() >= index) {
                result = matcher.group(index);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then inject the jar file into the database by running the following sql statement on the database:

```
CALL SQLJ.REMOVE_JAR('App.StoredProcedures', 0);
CALL SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR('C:\dev\DbExamples\dist\DbExamples.jar', 'App.StoredProcedures', 0);
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath', 'App.StoredProcedures');
```

Now create the stored procedure in the database by running the following sql statement:

```
drop function regex;
create function regex(sourceString varchar(8000), regex varchar(8000), index int)
returns varchar(8000)
parameter style java no sql
language java external name 'DbExamples.StoredProcedures.StringUtilities.regex';
```

Now you can run your query:

```
select
    regex('Joe Bloggs', '(\w+)\s(\w+)', 2) as surname
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Which returns:

```
Bloggs
```